# Перезагрузить collectionView после present modal view

Tags: swift

Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Вызываю новую view из tabBarController

```
let addVC = AddTransactionController()
    addVC.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "plus-1.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    let top: CGFloat = (view.frame.height < 700) ? 10 : 20
    addVC.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: top, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    
    viewControllers = [homeVC, addVC, profileVC]

extension TabBarController: UITabBarControllerDelegate {
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    let isAddVC = viewController is AddTransactionController

    if isAddVC {
        let addVC = AddTransactionController()
        if let sheet = addVC.sheetPresentationController {
            sheet.detents = [.large()]
        }
        addVC.addViewWillDisapper = {
            self.hVC.reloadLastTransaction()
        }
        self.present(addVC, animated: true)
        return false
    }
    
    return true
}
```

}

В AddTransactionController при закрытии вызывается closure

```
 var addViewWillDisapper: (()->())?

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    addViewWillDisapper?()
}
```

Функция, которая должна отработать на экране, находящемся под modal view

```
 func reloadLastTransaction() {
    loadInformation()
    self.lastTransactionsCollectionView?.reloadData()
}
```

функция отрабатывает, информация загружается, но collectionView не перезагружается. Перезагрузка происходит, только если перейти на любой не модально вызванный экран.

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Каким способом можно перезагрузить collectionView после закрытия модального окна?

Comment: Если у вас в loadInformation() асинхронная загрузка данных, то скорее всего reloadData() просто нечего обновить, т.к. данные еще не пришли. Т.е. нужно вызвать reloadData() в loadInformation(), в блоке получения данных.

Comment: Пробовал. И проверял, что нужная информация действительно загружается. Но срабатывает reloadData() только если вызвать его уже после завершения closure

Comment: Как вариант, попробуйте вызвать self.lastTransactionsCollectionView?.reloadData() во viewWillAppear, на экране, находящемся под modal view.

Comment: При закрытии modal view на экране находящемся под ним, не вызывается viewWillAppear